# Add data array into existing property

Tags: c#, json.net

I've tried different solutions but I'm not reaching anywhere.

I'm in a middle of a loop and sometimes I need to add data to an existing property (`details` in this case).

So, in the beginning I create the following JObject without any problem:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new {
      details = new[]{ 
        new{product_name        = detail["product_name"].ToString(), 
            quantity            = detail["quantity"].ToString(),
            product_options     = detail["product_options"].ToString()},
      }
    }
);

// _elements is an dictionary<int, JObject>
_elements.Add(id, JObject.Parse(json));

// output 
{
    "details": [

        {
            "product_name": "Oranges",
            "quantity": "2",
            "product_options": [],
        }

    ]
}
```

But, for some reason, I need to add more products to the list of `details`, so I would like my output to be:

```
{
    "details": [

        {
            "product_name": "Oranges",
            "quantity": "2",
            "product_options": [],
        },

        {
            "product_name": "Coca Cola",
            "quantity": "5",
            "product_options": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried so far without any success:

```
dic.Value.Property("details").Add(json);
dic.Value.SelectToken("details").Add(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

```
dic.Value["details"].Last.AddAfterSelf(JObject.Parse(json));
```